# How can I make a fighter that maxes out damage dealt?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, fighter

One of my players wants me to help him make a very strong fighter (with or without multiclassing as long as it includes at least 1 level of fighter) capable of dealing a lot of damage. He saw the Pal5/Rogue3 multiclass that makes tons of damage from auto-crit & smite and he asked me if there's something equally strong for a fighter.

The party consists of a fighter, a monk, and a rogue. The campaign style is urban questing, with extremely low to no magic use (hence the party has no caster).

The campaign has low to no magic use so I prefer the damage to be non-magical; anything melee or ranged is ok.

### Requirements

- Please only content that has been published in official printed books from WotC. No Unearthed Arcana content.
- Viable and correct for levels 1-20
- Preferably mundane damage
- No optional rules included (no flanking, no facing, etc.)
- Looking for Highest single round damage output, not consistent damage through fight/day
- There are only 1-2 encounters per day.

Comment: This meta on [the (on-)topicality of character optimization questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1639/23970) does a nice job of outlining some good tips for framing such a question. I suggest it both to OP and those thinking to answer.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure if we can come up with a max mundane nova damage build that is correct for 1-20, but I'll let others handle that :). It may be too broad of a request. However, I think it is stackable, it's just a lot of work :P

Comment: Will you allow spellcasting classes at all? Or just martial classes?

Comment: I'm voting to close because I think that there's still a *lot* unknown around magic. Mundane damage is easy, but are you allowing *haste*? A *belt of giant giant strength*? I think that buffs/equipment are a big part of this, likely. Of course, if you (voters) think this can be answered with every answerer having to tackle all those inidividually, feel free to override me.

Comment: Also, *if* magical effects are allowed (like *haste*) do we assume the buffs are pre-cast by friends (and, thus, effectively "free") or does this fighter have to somehow cast them? And I think "preferring" mundane damage either has to become a hard requirement or the line has to go. We can't calculate preferences. (Unless you say weight any magical damage by a factor of X%, I suppose.)

Comment: I'd still like to invite you to [chat] to help workshop this. I think we can make this stackable, or at least help guide you to figure out what your player is really trying to get and make everyone happy.